# Cannot see loggly-winston debug log in UI

Tags: node.js, typescript, winston, loggly

I cannot see any logs when I call `winston.debug`.  I think it is because I need to change the log level allowed to be seen?  [Link to winston documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-logging-levels).  [Loggly node.js documentation](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/loggly/content/admin/node-js-logs-2.htm).

Installation `npm i winston-loggly-bulk @types/winston-loggly-bulk winston`

```
import { Loggly, LogglyOptions } from "winston-loggly-bulk";
import winston from 'winston';

export class Server {
    private logOptions: LogglyOptions = {
        token: "my-customer-token",
        subdomain: "myDomain.com",
        tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
        json: true,
    };
    private logger: winston.Logger;
    private test: Test;

    constructor() {
        this.logger = winston.add(new Loggly(this.logOptions));

        this.test = new Test(this.logger);

        this.logger.info("mark1");   // I can see this in the loggly UI
        this.logger.debug("mark2");  // I cannot see this log in the loggly UI
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted loggly's support and they told me to set winston's [`level`](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-levels)

```
private logOptions: LogglyOptions = {
    token: "my-customer-token",
    level: config.production ? "error" : "debug",
    subdomain: "myDomain.com",
    tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
    json: true,
};
```

I created an `enum` to use for convenience:

```
export enum WinstonLogLevelsEnum {
    ERROR = "error",
    WARN = "warn",
    INFO = "info",
    HTTP = "http",
    VERBOSE = "verbose",
    DEBUG = "debug",
    SILLY = "silly",
};
```